# how to avoid paging if there is only 1 page in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I am using paging to list down Cadidates from Database. I am listing out 12 record in a page. I dont want paging to be shown if have only 1 page with details to be listed. Pls Help me out. The following is my code. 
Contoller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(int? page, int? filter)
    {
        ViewBag.statusName = db.CandidateStatuses.ToList();
        int pageSize = 12;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        var candidates = new List<Candidate>();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Filter = filter;
            candidates = db.Candidates.Where(m => m.CandidateStatusID == filter).OrderByDescending(m => m.CandidateID).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            candidates = db.Candidates.OrderByDescending(m => m.CandidateID).ToList();
        }

        return View(candidates.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

View:

```
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, filter = ViewBag.Filter }))
```

I Have Displayed only the code for paging part in my view. Pls help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved the problem.

```
 @{
if(Model.PageCount > 1)
{
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, filter = ViewBag.Filter }))
}
}
```

Comment: you should use @ before if, and remove unnecessary { }

Answer (score 7):

I think it should work:

```
@if(Model.PageCount > 1)
{
  Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
  @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, filter = ViewBag.Filter }))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked but not completely though as it still shows like 'page 1 of 1' but it removed the page number.

Comment: No i actually tried this myself but it gives me an error.

Comment: @if(Model.PageCount > 1)
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The if block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Comment: its just a syntactical error, you should fix it at your level.

Comment: Yea i know bro but Actually its not abt the brackets as its shown. I think its jus not right using that statement inside if condition the Error is shown inside the code as at the 'page@(model' part as only assignment, increment statements can be used and new objects cant be used as expression.

Comment: @Jerry, I had the exact same problem as you. All i had to do was add a < p > tag around it to tell the compiler that its parsing html code. And that fixed the problem. See edit below.

Answer (score 3):

Stack overflow, rejected my edit, and suggested I add it as an answer.

For fixing the whole section, add a < p > tag around the "Page X of Y ". That will avoid the "parser error" mentioned in the comment section above.

```
@{if(Model.PageCount > 1)
  {
  <p>Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount<p>
  @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, filter = ViewBag.Filter }))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just found this - too bad didn't find it earlier. A lot of built in options:

http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/PagedList.Mvc/PagedList.Mvc/PagedListRenderOptions

and the one needed here is:

```
new PagedListRenderOptions{ Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded }
```

http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/PagedList.Mvc/PagedList.Mvc/PagedListRenderOptions/P/Display